# Record view to create conditional statement in the template

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a method in controller that will load three different views based on if statement, like this

```
if(one) {
    $T->L->V('oneview')
}  

if(two) {
    $T->L->V('twoview')
}  

if(three) {
    $T->L->V('threeview')
}
```

In the all of the views, I have set one similar template. Say that this template named "menu-exporter" for these three different views.

In this menu-exporter template, there is a button to do something.

```
   <button> A Link that will generate the button </button>
```

What I want to achieve now is, How do I Record view to create conditional statement in the template, so that I can create a different link to this button in this template?

Like this one:

```
  if($view == 'oneview') {
   <button> The link go to the school </button>
  }

  if($view == 'twoview') {
   <button> The link go to the office  </button>
  }

  if($view == 'threeview') {
   <button> The link go to the home</button>
  }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the best way you can do is, sent the link to your view from your controller as code bellow

```
if(one) {
    $data['my_link'] = "link1";
    $T->L->V('oneview')
}  

if(two) {
    $data['my_link'] = "link2";
    $T->L->V('twoview')
}  

if(three) {
    $data['my_link'] = "link3";
    $T->L->V('threeview')
}
```

and use the `my_link` variable to generate your button link or href as

```
<button> <?php echo $my_link;?> </button>
```

This way, you keep your view clean and business logic in your controller.